# Wordpress Sub directory to root move

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to move a WP installation from a sub directory to the root. Ive done this plenty of times on other sites but im having a bit of an issue. I move the wp-* folders and files to root.

From: site.com/new/

To: site.com

I changed the WP Address and site address to not have the sub. When I go to view the site it redirects to site.com/newsletter/

I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: check your .htaccess file

Answer (score 2):

Check your .htaccess file.

Change these two lines.

```
RewriteBase /newsletter/
```

to

```
RewriteBase /
```

and

```
RewriteRule . /newsletter/index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```